# finding frequency of between moving frequency source and listener

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A person and a speaker is moving against each other at a velocity of 10ms-1 and 5ms-1 respectively. If frequency of speaker is 60hz and velocity of sound in the medium is 340ms-1. Find frequency with respect to person before and after crossing the speaker.

This is the question 
I found wavelength of the speaker is at rest 5.67m 
Before crossing the speaker by person velocity as 340+15 and found frequency equal to 62.6hz and for after velocity 340+5-10 and frequency 59hz .

The problem is that the answer in my book is before 627hz and after 574hz

What did I do wrong?can anyone please help me

Comment: You forgot some dot in the answer, should be 62.7hz and after 57.4hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand how you performed your calculations, and it feels like you tried to put everything together in the calculation pot. Remember that formulae are not magical ;)

Somewhere in your message should appear the word "Doppler effect", which is the phenomena at stake.

The situations of the emitter and receiver are not symmetric. If the receiver goes away faster than the speed of sound, he/she will never receive the signal, so frequency does not make sense. This should point you towards the idea that it is not simply the velocity difference that is involved here.

Try the following two-step reasoning. The source is moving, what is the frequency in the restframe, where the signal velocity is measured ? The receiver is moving, how is the frequency modified *with respect to the restframe* ? This should lead you to the correct answer (I checked that the results are in agreement with your textbook :D)